# Windows Service Facebook C# SDK Architecture

Tags: c#, .net, service, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-oauth

We have what we believe should not be an uncommon scenario but cannot find any guidance.

We have one account which has multiple pages one for each of our brands.  We need a Windows Service which runs unatended to periodically make posts to the various pages after checking a database for prescheduled posts.

The only problem we see is authentication.  Even though the Twitter API also uses oAuth, we are able to get an access code from Twitter that never expires and use it to make all of our API calls. What I need is the equivalent in Facebook API.  Lacking that, I need a way to be able to do what I describe above.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

~ DCT

Answer (score 8):

I've just done something similar from a windows service to post to my own feed.  I used the facebook sdk (http://csharpsdk.org/)

As you suggested in your question the problems are mainly to do with authentication.  In the end I found this:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/

Once you've got your app setup with the correct permission on the account you want to post to, you can get a non-expiring token just using your browser (just add in the app id and app secret):

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
        client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
       &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
       &grant_type=client_credentials
```

This will return an access token that doesn't expire, I just pasted this into my app.config....

Also:
Note that because you are not using a user access token, all calls to publish information on behalf of the user should reference /[USER FB ID] instead of /me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this using Task Scheduler and PowerShell with http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com (so you don't need to create a Windows Service). The scheduled script would read the token for each page with Read-FBConnection and then create posts with New-FBPost. You first set up the token files with New-FBConnection -PageId and Write-FBConnection -- these take care of the OAuth gunk for you.

Some cautions:

Facebook Offline Access Removal (http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) is coming, which will cause the tokens to eventually time out. Current tokens should be good for at least a couple months, and I will soon have a new version of the module which should be able to create page tokens which will never expire (not user tokens, just page tokens).

Posts created by Facebook Graph API may come marked with the "application" which created them. I named my default app "Owner" to make this less obtrusive. You can use my app or make your own.

Facebook Graph API supports creating posts, but does not support @-links within those posts.

Facebook can and does change their API and break backward-compatibility of automated systems. Offline Access Removal is just one instance of that. You will need to keep an eye on the Facebook developer blog.

Comment: I will try this but I have a couple of concerns and comments.  First, I really do feel the the need to build this into our service which already handles other Social APIs. The need to access the database and check for work to be done calls for some sort of program wrapper and I have already written that service.  That's not a problem since I can make Powershell calls from a .Net application.

Comment: Great, please let me know how it goes. Please follow up in the FacebookPSModule.codeplex.com discussion area.